Can we say anything about this recursive integral equation?
Let $0 \le B(r)$ with $0 < r$ be truncated function, all real.
The truncation is \forall r_${max} \le r: B(r) =0; \forall r \le r_{min}: B(r) =0$
For $0<x$, define $I(x) = \int^x_1{B(r)dr}$ and a series with constants $0 < a,b$. $r_1 = a; r_n(a) = a + b \cdot I(r_{n-1}(a))$.
We are interested in resolving the recursion and in $r_{\infty}=r_n \text{ with } n=\min(n | r_n=r_{n+1})$, and $
\sigma^+ = \min(0 < a | r_{max} \le r_{\infty}(a))$$
I think $r_{\infty} = a + b \cdot I(r_{\infty})$ is true. From that, I derive $a + b \cdot I(r_{\infty}) = a + b \cdot I(a + b \cdot I(r_{\infty}))$; $I(r_{\infty}) = I(a + b \cdot I(r_{\infty})),$ and with $r_{\infty}(\sigma+) = I_{\infty}$, we get $ I_{\infty} = I(\sigma^+ + b \cdot I_{\infty}).$
Furthermore, consider a point change in $B$: $\tilde{B}(r) = B(r) + \Delta B \cdot \delta(r=\tilde{r})$. We can compute the resulting changes as
$\partial I_{\infty} = \Delta B \frac{\partial I(x)}{\partial x} = B(x) \partial I(\sigma^+ + b \cdot I_{\infty}) = B(\sigma^+ + b \cdot I_{\infty})\cdot(\partial\sigma^+ + b\cdot\partial I_{\infty}),$
allowing us to solve $\partial\sigma^+ = \Delta B\cdot(\frac{1}{B(\sigma^+ + b \cdot I_{\infty})}-b).$
Questions

Are my above conclusions correct?
Bonus. Can we say anything nice (for example non-recursive) about $I(r_n), r_n, r_{\infty}$ or $\partial I(r_n), \partial r_n, \partial r_{\infty}$?


"Can we say anything nice about (...)?" is too vague a question. Please be specific.
